# How to download app from apps.ubuntu.com?

Tags: installation, 13.04

When I tried to click on this button to download app using any web browsers e.g. Firefox, Chrome.

[image]

I got this windows popped up.

[image]

What application I need to choose so I can install apps using web browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This needs to open with Software Center.  Click on choose, and for browse for Ubuntu Software Center in `/usr/bin/software-center`.

[image]

[image]